# Adding Nuget Packages From One Project To Another

Tags: c#, nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to add all nuget packages from another project into this project. I copied all the folders under packages from one project into this one how do I add to visual studio?

I tried using the Package Manager Console to update the nuget packages but I am not sure what to write?

I tried Update-Package -Reinstall -Solution Babysitter2 [Babysitter2]

What am I doing wrong?

This Is what my project setup looks like.

[image: Here Is What my project looks like]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If both projects are on the same solution all you have to do is: `install-package package-name ...` on the Package Manager Console selecting the project and it would notice the package already installed and would just add a reference to your selected project otherwise you may wanna try local repositories

Comment: They are not in the same solution. Am I supposed to be referencing the original project I took it from?

Comment: And then why not pull them from Nuget.org by simply issuing `install-package` commands or you can right click your project in the Solution Explorer and hit the "Manage Nuget Packages" item and you'll be presented with an UI, maybe that'll work better for you

Comment: As Luiso states, manage from the *solution level*, not the project level. In this way, you can add packages to multiple projects at one time.

Answer (score 32):

Simply copy existing `packages.config` file to your new project. Include this file into the project. Then follow to `Package Manager Console` and execute `Update-Package -reinstall` command. No need to copy `packages` folder and to add dll 
references manually.

Comment: Getting an error  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], InvalidOperationException

Comment: @N.Sch try to remove `packages` folder before running update command. Also try to update Nuget.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks

Answer (score 26):

You can install packages on the new project based on installed packages in another project.

1. Clique on "Tools/Nuget Package Manager/Package Manager Console" to open the "Package manager Console"
2. On "Package Manager Console", paste the following command replacing sourceProject and TargetProject by your project names:

   ```
   Get-Package -ProjectName sourceProject   | ForEach-Object { Install-Package -Id $_.Id -Version $_.Versions -Projectname targetProject }
   ```

Comment: This is a beauty. Thank you.

Comment: what should I exactly write insted of -ProjectName ,sourceProject   and targetProject ?!

Comment: @amirkian replace `sourceProject` with the original project, and `targetProject` with the new name, leave else the same

Comment: Do we have to give the complete path of both projects or just the name would do the work?

Comment: I gave it the name of my project and it says it can't find it. How do we deal with spaces?

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do it to go to:
Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

Then you can see all the packages for the solution on the left hand side. Click on one of them and on the right hand side you can choose the project that you want it to be installed.

[image]

Comment: This is an developer friendly and easy way to share packages with projects in the same solution.

Comment: This is a tedious way to copy ALL the nuget packages from one project to another like the question asks. The answer by Alvaro Pereira will be the quickest and simplest to copy all packages even if there was around 30+ packages.

Answer (score 1):

Project references (libraries included in the project) are tracked in the project settings (.csproj file). Packages under the packages directory should not be managed by hand - that directory is supposed to be managed by nuget, so any files you place there by hand are erroneous. You should have your required nuget packages listed in packages.config, and then just Restore them from nuget, which will download them and put them in the packages directory.

Comment: So if I copy and paste the packages.config file from my old project to new project. Will that automatically add those nuget package to my current project?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it will add the references - you might have to copy the references between the .csproj files (NOT the entire file, just the necessary references! You'll have to be comfortable editing the XML!) The "easy" way to do this is really just to add the same packages again via NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

All the installed NuGet packages saved on *"C:\Users\AhadMavilab.nuget\packages"* if your package exist on there, you can simply go to the project configuration file and add your package reference to ItemGroup.
for example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```